# Get the whole row from a MATCH result?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

When in a cell I do MATCH("AS032",Sheet2!A:A,0) let's say I'll get a result something like 402 (The number on the row where the match was found). Is there a formula where I can get the whole row address like Sheet2!402:402 ?

With ADDRESS I'm getting the cell address (Sheet2!$A$402), but I need the whole row?

> EDIT:
>
> I Tried with CONCATENATE but the result back is quoted (I'm passing in
>   as parameter in another formula) and it just fails the outer formula.

EDIT2:

Including a screenshot:
[image]

The Current formula that I am using is:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!4:4,MATCH(I3,1:1,0))
```

If I use `=INDEX(MATCH(H3,A:A,0),MATCH(I3,1:1,0))` I am getting #REF even as array formula

Comment: I am a little confused. You have a formula in one cell, and you then want to squeeze and entire row into that cell? Or what am I not getting?

Comment: I just need to find the whole row i.e. Sheet1!235:235, so I can use it later for INDEX-MATCH to find another value.

Comment: Basic, I need to look in Column A and find a value, than I need to look in Row 1 and find a different value, and the final result will be the interception of both of them. The problem is both of the values are user chosen and I need to address them first

Comment: But the `INDEX()` functions takes the row (as an integer) as input (alongside a column and an array). So why would you not want the row number, that `MATCH()` returns?

Comment: Ive made another edit, please see the screenshot might explain a bit more. What I want to do is replace "Sheet1!4:4" with a formula that will give me the same result but use the value from H3 which is chosen by dropdown by a user. I3 is also picked by dropdown by user

Comment: I tried =INDEX(CONCATENATE(MATCH(H3,A:A,0),":",MATCH(H3,A:A,0)),MATCH(I3,1:1,0)) and gives me #VALUE as result because the result from CONCATENATE is quoted like "4:4" instead only 4:4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like the `INDIRECT()` function?

> =INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("A"; 402; ":XX"; 402))

Comment: That's it, I wasn't aware of INDIRECT function. So what does this exactly?

Comment: @al1en It takes a text and converts it into a reference that excel can understand, if possible, otherwise it will throw an error.

Comment: Thanks about explanation @Jerry